# problem in reterving integer value in shellscript

Tags: shell

pro* c code: shan.pc

```
int main()
{
    return 8000;
}
```

shellscript:

```
#!/bin/ksh
declare -i rc

shan
rc=$?

echo "$rc";
```

in script I called proc executable i got an output 128, rather then 8000. how can i receive
8000 in shellscript?  please help me out?

solution:

```
int main()
    {
count=8000;
prinf("counter %d",count); 
        return 0;
    }

#!/bin/ksh
  rc=$(shan | awk '/counter/{print $2}')      
  echo "$rc";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't; the exit status of a program is restricted to -128 .. 127.  `printf()` it instead and use `rc=$(shan)` in the script.

Comment: i gave like this rc=$(shan),no value is getting printted.

Comment: Did you change `shan.pc` to `printf` the value instead of `return`ing it?

Comment: do u mean int main() { printf(8000);}

Comment: `int main() { printf("%d\n", 8000); return 0; }`  You're going to need to learn C if you're going to get anywhere with this.

Comment: i need to receive the value in script, in c i know it will print 8000.i need to echo the value in script which i receive from proc.. i dont need any printf. I am using a counter variable in a loop. i want this value of the counter to be  returned to the script...

Comment: Again, *you can't*.  8000 is too large to be passed back with `return`, which is why I used `printf` and then the `$(shan)` syntax which captures the printed output from your program.

Comment: The problem is i have several printf in my .pc file but i need only this 8000 to be returned to the script... is there any way to handle this case? In script i need to make calculations with this value 8000.

Comment: I can think of several ways, none of which are particularly friendly.  The easiest is probably to write it to a file and use `rc=$(< filename)` to read it into the script.  There are other solutions involving passing file descriptors around, but that gets rather ugly and unmaintainable.

Comment: i got the soultion:  rc=$(shan | awk '/counter/{print $2}') echo "$rc";    in proc i used i used count=8000;prinf("counter %d",count);